# debconf-i18n depends on debconf (= 1.5.58ubuntu2); however: Version of debconf on system is 1.5.58ubuntu1

Tags: software-installation, debconf

when I tried to install git in Ubuntu 16.04,

```
 sudo apt-get install git
```

```
debconf-i18n : Depends: debconf (= 1.5.58ubuntu2) but 1.5.58ubuntu1 is to be installed
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (> 1:2.7.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (< 1:2.7.4-.) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

To resolve this problem,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall debconf=1.5.58ubuntu2
```

but I got the error in the following.

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/debconf.prerm: 15: /var/lib/dpkg/info/debconf.prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 15: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/debconf_1.5.58ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/debconf.postinst: 75: /var/lib/dpkg/info/debconf.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/debconf_1.5.58ubuntu2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The install command is : `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git`

Answer (score 0):

Manually editing the offending files`/var/lib/dpkg/info/debconf.prerm` worked for me

From this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/979022/1025261