# dpkg returned an error code(1)

Tags: dpkg

Whenever i'm trying to install any program Ubuntu is showing this ;

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gedit
Suggested packages:
  gedit-plugins
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gedit
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 83 not upgraded.
24 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/408 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,192 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 281827 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gedit_3.28.1-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gedit.prerm: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/info/gedit.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old gedit package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gedit_3.28.1-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new gedit package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gedit.postinst: 32: /var/lib/dpkg/info/gedit.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed gedit package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gedit_3.28.1-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You haven't told us your release of Ubuntu, but do you have `python3-minimal` installed?  (it's the package that contains py3clean which all Ubuntu releases should have installed; your `gedit` package looks like 18.04 but why make us guess)

Comment: I'm sorry it is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: Please edit your question and show the output from `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 16.04 Completely broken python3 + dpkg + apt-get!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092919/ubuntu-16-04-completely-broken-python3-dpkg-apt-get)

Answer (score 0):

The two important lines from the log you posted are:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gedit.prerm: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/info/gedit.prerm: py3clean: not found
```

and:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gedit.postinst: 32: /var/lib/dpkg/info/gedit.postinst: py3compile: not found
```

They tell us that you're missing `py3clean` and `py3compile`, both of which are part of a Python install (specifically, Python 3).  Your Python is broken.

There are a couple of things you can do to fix this.  Try running

```
apt-get -f install
```

and/or

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

as root.  Both of these will try to find and fix broken dependencies.  If they don't work (and they might well not -- they're useful commands to try, but not panaceas), try the steps given by various answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786156/apt-get-update-not-working-due-to-unmet-dependencies/979022).

Comment: i have tried all of those commands to reset up my system but still it is not working !!