# sudo apt-get install vim -- is not working, failed with dependency issues

Tags: apt, package-management, python3

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
vim is already the newest version (2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.3).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3 : Depends: dh-python but it is not installable
 python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-pkg-resources (= 20.7.0-1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

further tried to run `apt-get -f install  vim`  but again same error.

Comment: The output says that you already have vim installed!  
Run `sudo apt-get -f install` without vim to fix the issues.

Comment: I would check your sources (you didn't provide release details, but it looks like xenial), and your python3 version (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3-setuptools shows correct source for xenial thus check sources, https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3, https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=vim)

Answer (score 3):

First, you have vim installed, and it is the newest version. You don't need to install it.

Second, you have some issues with Python packages. To solve them:
  - Run `sudo apt-get -f install` then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Finally, run `sudo apt-get -f install`.
  - If the problem is not solved, run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3`

Comment: Thank for your response. 
Yes, your right there issue with python package. when I tried to run "Sudo apt-get -f install" , its also throwing error. the error as below.
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.prerm: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-pip
 python3-setuptools
 python3-wheel
 python3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786156/apt-get-update-not-working-due-to-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score -2):

If not worked after `sudo apt-get -f install`, run the command `sudo apt-get update` to update.